# How can I create a button when a user click all selected text must be align on the center of rich textbox in c#

Tags: c#

Hie, I have tried my best to create a button when a user click all selected text  must be align on the center of rich textbox in c# but Am still getting what I don't want. So please can somebody help me please.

Comment: let's see what you have tried...

Comment: what have you actually tried..? please show us vs telling us

Comment: Hello, please edit your question to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
richTextBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAligment.Center;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button's click event try this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
```

then you can center-align the selected part of text.

[The image for the result I got (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01c4K.png)

[The image for the result I got (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZGFU.png)